# where to start learning nokia application?

Tags: qt, programming-languages, nokia

i have no idea about the nokia app all i know it is used the c++ and QT SDK correct me if I am wrong.

any references or book will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, do you want to develop for Symbian or Maemo (more recent but available on less devices) ?

For Maemo, you could start with the SDK Virtual Image (to use in VirtualBox or VMWare):
http://maemovmware.garage.maemo.org/2nd_edition/

There is also a Virtual PC version, but I'm not sure if the image is as recent:
https://garage.maemo.org/projects/vpc-sdk

---

Otherwise, you could also check out the Nokia Forums, you could start here: http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/Other/Maemo/

Also, you should also get the QT Tools if you're doing cross-platform: http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Tools/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to google "Symbian":

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_do_I_start_programming_for_Symbian_OS%3F

Answer (score 1):

For Nokia phones, you have 2 types of applications:

1. Java application: J2ME, for feature phones (Series 40) and Symbian
2. QT: for Symbian and Maemo

The nokia forum is a great start for learning:

[www.forum.nokia.com](http://www.forum.nokia.com)